# Python humanize.naturalsize() remove trailing 0's in the fraction

Tags: python, humanize

Is it possible to get the output of

```
1M
1.01M
```

by changing the `format`'s value in the following code?

```
import  humanize

format = "%.2f"
raw1 = 1_048_576;
raw2 = 1_058_576

print(humanize.naturalsize(raw1, format=format, gnu=True));
print(humanize.naturalsize(raw2, format=format, gnu=True));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be post-process the string afterwards:

```py
import re

import humanize


def my_format(num, fmt="%.2f"):
    n = humanize.naturalsize(num, format=fmt, gnu=True)
    return re.sub(r"\.0+(?=\D)", "", n)


raw1 = 1_048_576
raw2 = 1_058_576

print(my_format(raw1))
print(my_format(raw2))
```

Prints:

```
1M
1.01M
```

Comment: Well, thanks. but it kind of defeats the purpose of using the library (I am re-writing my C# app in Python, and in C#, I manually created the "humanised" string. I heard Python has a library for that, so I thought I could use it to save coding). If I cannot achieve it with a format string, I guess I do the whole thing manually without using the library.

Answer (score 0):

No, any change to the format will apply to both outputs. Changing format to below will get the format of 1M but again, it applies to both.

```
format = "%1.0f"
```

Comment: Well, in C#, I could use a format string like `#.##` which does not print trailing zeros. (That is, that same format can print `1` and `1.01`.) So, I wondered if there is such a thing in Python, but it seems like there isn't.